# ggvis equivalent for coord_flip() in ggplot2?

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I'm just looking to display a box plot horizontally.
If you'd like an example (vertical) plot, try this

```
library(ddplyr)
library(shiny)
data.frame(theVar = c(1,5:10,15)) %>% ggvis(y = ~theVar, x = ~1) %>% layer_boxplots()
```

not sure if this is even possible without a hack...

Comment: I found [this link](http://www.qaster.com/q/446135547417743360/hadleywickham+is+there+a+coordfliplike+layer+in+ggvis). It seems that what you are asking may not be possible at the moment.